# Cannot read property 'x' of undefined array json

Tags: angular

I have this code

```
<div class="photo-gallery1" *ngIf="plans.attachments.length > 0">
...
</div>
```

and here is json which is plans

[image]

and I'm getting error

[image]

What can I do? I've tried `plans[0].attachments` as well but then error is that angular has no idea what 0 is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755336/angular2-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Comment: Ah.. better dupe, tagged the "wrong one": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734671/observable-type-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the safe navigation operator (`?.`) in the template:

```
*ngIf="plans?.attachments?.length > 0"
```

Your template is being parsed before the data is loaded. Which means it already tries to evaluate the statement, before `plans` has been properly set. The safe navigation operator (commonly mistaken for the elvis operator (`?:`)) is used to prevent null pointers in object parameter navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="photo-gallery1" *ngIf="plans?.attachments?.length > 0">
...
</div>
```

[Replacement of Elvis Operator of Angular2 in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247362/replacement-of-elvis-operator-of-angular2-in-typescript)