# Lodash get vs. es6 fallback values?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, redux, lodash

How does Lodash compare to using the new ES6 optional arguments?

I have the following code:

```
location: {
  latitude: response.pickupLocation.latitude || "",
  longitude: response.pickupLocation.longitude || ""
},
```

With Lodash I know I could run:

```
latitude: get(response, 'pickupLocation.latitude', '')
```

Or alternatively I could create a function that takes in the object and path and always returns `''`as the default fallback. Is there any advantage to using Lodash here other than the fact that the code would be shorter?

Comment: You mean `location: (({latitude = "", longitude = ""}) => ({latitude, longitude}))(response.pickupLocation)`? Or maybe just `location: Object.assign({latitude: "", longitude: ""}, response.pickupLocation)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The advantage of [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) is, you omit continuing checks if a property exist, which would be necessary.

```
latitude: response && response.pickupLocation && response.pickupLocation.latitude || "",
```

Answer (score 11):

For the latest browsers, or by using polyfills or transpiler, you could also use optional chaining and nullish coalescing operator like:

```
latitude: response?.pickupLocation?.latitude ?? ''
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. TY @Samyak Lal 

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with ES6, it is just the logical OR operator. "Optional arguments" sounds like you are relating to [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) but these are used in `function` signatures.

Personally, I would stick with the logical OR as it does not require an external library. Also I would recommend to never use strings when you want to access object properties because it complicates refactoring, usage search, the optional use of TypeScript, and hinders code completion.

If you want to make sure, that no exception occurs when you access a property of a null type, you can use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247362/replacement-of-elvis-operator-of-angular2-in-typescript/39247628#39247628):

```
getSafe(() => response.pickupLocation.latitude) || ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to @str's answer, if `response` does not have a `pickupLocation` property, this will result in a TypeError (Cannot read property latitude of undefined), regardless of the OR operator.

You could wrap this in a try-catch. Then you would return `response.pickupLocation.latitude || fallback` in try or `fallback` in a catch block.

This will not handle the defined by falsey values (imagine that `response.pickupLocation.latitude` is `0`). This function will return a `fallback` value, not `0`. This can be handled easily by checking typeof (`typeof response.pickupLocation.latitude !== 'undefined' ? response.pickupLocation.latitude : fallback`), however we are still talking about a hardcoded object path.
The same issue is presented on the accepted answer as well.

To handle this dynamically for any object path, you have to loop over a provided object, check for `hasOwnProperty` and peel off the nested properties by each iteration until you get to end of the specified path. Something like this:

```
const getSafe = (object, path, fallback) => {
    const fragments = path.split('.')
    let value

    for (let i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(fragments[i])) {
            return fallback;
        }
        value = object[fragments[i]];
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: "*Referring to @str's answer, if response does not have a pickupLocation property, this will result in a TypeError*"–No it won't. That is the whole point of using a `getSafe` function.